# access this context in class decorator

Tags: javascript

my decorator

```
function vote(target) {
  target.vote = (val = '') => {
    console.log(target.name + val);
  }
}


class Cat {
  @vote
  name = 'britanik';
  meow() { return `${this.name} says Meow!`}
}
let garfield = new Cat();

garfield.vote('please .....');
```

but target.name is undefined Why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make the target.vote a normal function and it should work just fine .

```
   function vote(target) {
  target.vote = function(val=""){
    console.log(this.name + val);
  };
}

class Cat {
  @vote name = "britanik";
  meow() {
    return `${this.name} says Meow!`;
  }
}
let garfield = new Cat();
garfield.vote("please .....");
```